# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript

Been trying to solve this issue for the past few days. Surprisingly, my checkbox and Localstorage all works but in console, it displays an error "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined**". I have tried my best to solve this issue to make the error go away but no luck. I know I am trying to call the "***.done***" property that doesn't exist but how do I solve this issue? I have google'd and read all similar questions on SO.

I don't think it's acceptable to ignore this error in console right? Can somebody please guide/help me? Please just JavaScript, no jQuery. Thanks!

The error comes from the function checkAll() and uncheckAll().

```
function checkAll() {
var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = getInputs.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
    getInputs[i].checked = true;            
    items[i].done = true; 
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));        
    }
}
```

and

```
function uncheckAll() {
var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = getInputs.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox') 
     getInputs[i].checked = false;               
     items[i].done = false; 
     localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
     } 
}
```

My code below:

```
<script>
  const addItems = document.querySelector('.add-items');
  const itemsList = document.querySelector('.plates');
  const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];

  function addItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const text = (this.querySelector('[name=item]')).value;
    const item = {
        text,
        done: false
    };

    items.push(item);
    populateList(items, itemsList);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    this.reset();
  }

  function populateList(plates = [], platesList) {
    platesList.innerHTML = plates.map((plate, i) => {
        return `
            <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-index=${i} id="item${i}" ${plate.done ? 'checked' : ''} />
            <label for="item${i}">${plate.text}</label>
            </li>
        `;
    }).join('');
  }

function toggleDone(e) {
    if(!e.target.matches('input')) return; //skip unless its an input
    const el = e.target;
    const index = el.dataset.index;
    items[index].done = !items[index].done;
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    populateList(items, itemsList);
}
  addItems.addEventListener('submit', addItem);
  itemsList.addEventListener('click', toggleDone);

  populateList(items, itemsList);

// Challenge: Button: clear all, check all, uncheck all

function checkAll() {
    var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, max = getInputs.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
        getInputs[i].checked = true;            
        items[i].done = true; 
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));        
        }
}

function uncheckAll() {
    var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, max = getInputs.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (getInputs[i].type === 'checkbox') 
         getInputs[i].checked = false;               
         items[i].done = false; 
         localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
         } 
}

function clearItem() {
    localStorage.clear();   
    var element = document.getElementById("plates");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    location.reload();      
    console.log('Items cleared in localStorage');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are initializing the array to empty, if there are no `items` set in `localstorage`

```
const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
```

It is possible that your `items[i]` could be `undefined`.

You need to change

```
items[i].done = false;  //similarly for true
```

to

```
items[i] = items[i] || {};
items[i].done = false; //or true
```

Comment: Thanks, it did get rid of the problem but now it adds heaps of random undefined items into my list.

Example: I had 3 items added to my checklist. Now every time I click check all, more items added as undefined as I refresh the page.

Comment: Without further ado, did some debugging and managed to fix my code. When added the code below:
    `items[i] = items[i] || {};`

My var getInputs was counting all the html elments as well together with the checkboxes. Changed to document.querySelectorAll instead of document.getElementsByTagName

Comment: @coderwong Good work, can you highlight the line of code you have modified for this?

Comment: When added the code above:
`items[i] = items[i] || {};`
Error dissappeared but when clicking check/uncheck all and refreshed the page, it created more list inputs. In the debugger mode in console, the input counted 8 elements (input + buttons). So it looped up to 8 max, instead of 3 checkboxes.

I changed the code under function checkAll() and uncheckAll():
`var getInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");` to
`var getInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");`

=)

Comment: @coderwong ohh, ok. I couldn't have figured this out without your markup being part of your problem statement.